# Convert xlxs to csv and Data Format

Tags: c#, .net, excel, save, converters

I have 2 problems when converting files:

1. I would like the date format to look like this:

```
19.08.2019
```

and it looks like this

```
8/19/2019
```

2.After conversion, additional lines with commas are added to the csv file. How can I overcome this?

```
11,900011,S1,8/19/2019,11,6.90,9.90,,18.50,,8.80,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
12,900012,S1,8/19/2019,12,6.70,8.80,,14.50,,9.40,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
....
```

I use a library

```
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

There is my code :

```
 public static void Convert()
        {
            try
            {
                Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
                //Load file . xlsx
                Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(Program.filePaths[1]);
                //Save file .csv
                wb.SaveAs(Program.filePaths[0], Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                wb.Close(false);
                app.Quit();


            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

i convert from excel to csv using npoi 
[npoi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/)
(sorry, for lose strings there, this is a copy from my projects)

```
        public Dictionary<string, string> ExceltoCsv(IWorkbook input)
    {
        var csvTrennzeichen = OutputSettings.ColumnSeparator.ToString();
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (var sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < input.NumberOfSheets; sheetIndex++)
        {
            var sheet = input.GetSheetAt(sheetIndex);
            var sheetresult = new List<string>();
            for (var row = sheet.FirstRowNum; row < sheet.LastRowNum; row++)
            {
                var rowObj = sheet.GetRow(row);
                if (rowObj.Cells.All(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(WertAuslesen(x))))
                    continue;

                var line = string.Join(csvTrennzeichen, rowObj.Cells
                                                        .Select(cell => WertAuslesen(cell).Replace("\r", " ").Replace("\n", " "))
                                                        .Select(cell => OutputSettings.Writeinquotes ? string.Format("\"{0}\"", cell.Replace("\"", "\"\"")) : cell));

                sheetresult.Add(line);
            }

            result.Add(sheet.SheetName, string.Join("\r\n", sheetresult));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private string WertAuslesen(ICell oldCell)
    {
        switch (oldCell.CellType)
        {
            case CellType.Boolean:
                return oldCell.BooleanCellValue.ToString();
            case CellType.Error:
                return oldCell.ErrorCellValue.ToString();
            case CellType.Formula:
                return oldCell.CellFormula;
            case CellType.Numeric:
                return !DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(oldCell)
                    ? oldCell.NumericCellValue.ToString(OutputSettings.GetDecimalFormat(Digits(oldCell.CellStyle.GetDataFormatString())))
                    : oldCell.DateCellValue.ToString(OutputSettings.DateFormat);
            case CellType.String:
                return oldCell.RichStringCellValue.ToString();
            case CellType.Unknown:
                return oldCell.StringCellValue;
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

    private static int Digits(string format)
    {
        var digits = format.ContainsAny(',', '.') ? format.Split(new[] { ',', '.' }).Last() : "";
        return digits.Length;
    }
```

i also feel the need add the outputsettings class since its clears things up, its not nececcary tho

```
    public class OutputSettings
{
    public static readonly OutputSettings Default = new OutputSettings(Encoding.UTF8, null, "yyyyMMdd", "hh:mm:ss", ".", "", "y", "n", ',', true, "", null);
    //I am immutable
    public OutputSettings(CultureInfo culture) : this(
        Encoding.UTF8,
        null,
        culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern,
        culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern,
        culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator,
        culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator,
        "y",
        "n",
        ',',
        true,
        "",
        null)
    {
    }

    public OutputSettings(
        Encoding encoding,
        Version ioVersion,
        string dateFormat,
        string timeFormat,
        string decimalSeperator,
        string thousandSeperator,
        string yesString,
        string noString,
        char columnseperator,
        bool writeinquotes,
        string outputFolder,
        IResourceHandler resourceHandler)
    {
        Encoding = encoding;
        IOVersion = ioVersion;
        DateFormat = dateFormat;
        TimeFormat = timeFormat;
        DecimalSeperator = decimalSeperator;
        ThousandSeperator = thousandSeperator;
        YesString = yesString;
        NoString = noString;
        ColumnSeparator = columnseperator;
        Writeinquotes = writeinquotes;
        OutputFolder = outputFolder;
        ResourceHandler = resourceHandler;
    }

    public IResourceHandler ResourceHandler { get; }

    public Encoding Encoding { get; }

    public Version IOVersion { get; }

    public string DateFormat { get; }

    public string TimeFormat { get; }

    public string DateTimeFormat => DateFormat + " " + TimeFormat;

    public string DecimalSeperator { get; }

    public string ThousandSeperator { get; }

    public string DecimalFormat => GetDecimalFormat(2);

    public string YesString { get; }

    public string NoString { get; }

    private char _columnseperator;
    public char ColumnSeparator
    {
        get
        {
            return _columnseperator;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (value != ',' && value != ';')
                throw new ArgumentException(Localization.Resources.StaticTranslationResource.IO_SEPARATOR_MUSS_COMMA_ODER_SEMICOLON_SEIN);
            _columnseperator = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Writeinquotes { get; }
    public string OutputFolder { get; set; }

    public string GetDecimalFormat(int precision)
    {
        if (precision < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(Localization.Resources.StaticTranslationResource.OUTPUT_ANZAHL_DER_STELLEN_DARF_NICHT_NEGATIV_SEIN, nameof(precision));

        var sb = new StringBuilder($"#{ThousandSeperator}##0{DecimalSeperator}");
        if (precision == 0)
        {
            sb.Append('#');
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < precision; i++)
            {
                sb.Append('0');
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

edit: im using alot of extensionmethods to make my code readably
containsany is one of them

```
        public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> superset, params T[] subset) => !subset.Except(superset).Any();

    public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> superset, IEnumerable<T> subset) => !subset.Except(superset).Any();

    public static bool ContainsAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> superset, params T[] subset) => subset.Any(superset.Contains);

    public static bool ContainsAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> superset, IEnumerable<T> subset) => subset.Any(superset.Contains);
```

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately I need a function that uses "Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;".  Do you have any idea?

Comment: well  you could use the same sheme i used, by iterating over the columns and rows, excel interop should tell you the dimensions of your sheet, and then join the strings

Comment: or reopen the csv, remove trailing empty lines and replace the date separators with regex  like: Regex.Replace(wholeCsvAsString, "([0-9][0-9]?)\/([0-9][0-9]?)\/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])","$2.$1.$3")

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the date, if your date is formatted correctly in Excel, Excel should respect that format when it exports to CSV.  I assume it's not clobbering your existing format; it's just exporting as-is, right?

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
sheet.Columns[4].NumberFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd";
```

As far as the extra columns/rows...  that means that "something" is in those cells, even if it's just formatting.  If you do column/row deletes, it will prevent them from being exported when you save as CSV.

If you don't know what's there, the simple way to do this is to find the last row with "real" data, and this counts on you knowing how to define that...  maybe any row with no content in columns A, B and E.  Take the row after the last real row, and delete everything down to the last row of `UsedRange.`

Alternatively, you can use the built-in `CountA` function in Excel, which should be very fast.  If the function returns 0 for the row, you can count on nothing being in any cell in that row.  Quick example:

```
Excel.Range last = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell,
    Type.Missing);

for (int row = last.Row; row > 0; row++)
{
    Excel.Range r = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[row, 1];
    double o = addIn.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.EntireRow);
    if (o == 0)
        r.EntireRow.Delete();
}
```

Untested but should be 99% there...  I think you need to go from the bottom up, but not 100% sure.  My thought is it will skip rows on delete if you don't.